# How to copy and paste HTML (including images) from password protected pages?

Tags: google-docs, google-chrome, html, copy-paste, linux

I want to copy HTML (including images) from a web page to google docs.

This works fine if the web page is public.

But if the page needs a login, then the images are not inserted into google docs.

I use the latest Chrome version on Ubuntu Linux.

Is there a way to copy HTML including the images from password protected pages?

Comment: Have you tried copy-paste content from different Content Management Systems? If so, please add the name. Have you tried to use the Chrome Developers tools to inspect the HTML code and find the source of the images? Does the images have a file extension or the are generated by code on the fly?

Comment: Yes, I have tried different system which need authentication. Gitlab is one of them. Why should I find the source of the image? This is not related to the image. I guess the clipboard contains the html. For example `<img src="https://foo.com/pic.png">`. If the access to pic.png is password protected, then google docs can't access the image.

Comment: Some CMS use temporary / "special" URLs for serving images and other resources specially when those resources are set to prevent being downloaded copied. The clipboard will contain the HTML only if you copied the HTML as text value, otherwise the clipboard have an "object". Please add the steps that you are following for doing the copy-paste operation including enough details so others can replicate the issue.

Comment: You said "Some CMS use temporary / "special" URLs".... The URLs are not special. You just need the correct authentication for accessing the content. The steps are "copy on gitlab private repo", switch browser tab to google docs. Then paste from clipboard.

Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: I just did a copy-paste from a GitHub private repo of the rendered content including an image of a Readme.md file and it worked fine. Please [edit] the question to add enough details so others can reproduce your issue and clarify if by HTML you mean code from the raw view of an HTML file, the rendered content or a md file, issue, comment, wiki, etc. Consider to include some screenshots.